# Sencha touch Add two Badgetext on same button

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

My problem is I have to add 2 badgetext on the same Contact button.. one is to show the newly added leads count and other is newly added contacts count.. i can able to put one badge text on button.. But no idea how to add two at the same button.. please help me to solve this issue.. Thanks in advance

here is my button code

```
 {
                xytpe: 'button',
                cls: 'wishlogbtn1',
                id: 'calendarbtn'
                badgeText: '6'



            }
```

Comment: I dont think this is supported. You might need to implement this your self.

Comment: do u have any examples to suggest ..

Comment: I didnt find any threads related to this ..plz help me to find one ..

Comment: Working exmaple 
https://github.com/jerome76/MultiBadgeButton